# Can't heroku open

Tags: django, heroku

When I do heroku open I have "application error" in my browser so I check my logs with "heroku logs --tail --app " and get the following:

```
2017-07-29T11:06:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-07-29T11:06:41.268744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn harrispierceDjango.wsgi --log-file -`
2017-07-29T11:06:43.032101+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found

...

2017-07-29T11:20:08.108114+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=harrispierce.herokuapp.com request_id=6617f7a2-6599-41aa-9708-846828430bad fwd="82.229.220.87" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I followed the step by step procedure but never did anything related to the databases: could it be related?

Thanks,

Comment: No. Why would you think that? The error is telling you clearly that it cannot find gunicorn. Did you install it?

Comment: Yep I added it to my requirements.txt and ran "heroku run pip install gunicorn". Same error...

Comment: I now get: "gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>". python manage.py runserver works though... Any idea?

Comment: `heroku open` tries to run your application _locally_. Therefore you shouldn't install `gunicorn` via `heroku run`; that would cause the command to run remotely. (Even when running on Heroku you shouldn't install dependencies this way. The Python buildpack will automatically install dependencies from `requirements.txt` for you when you deploy. Doing it manually is redundant and useless due to Heroku's ephemeral file system.)

Comment: Your second issue is distinct from your first. Please ask a new question, and make sure to include all relevant information, e.g. the contents of your `Procfile`.